# FAILED: IllegalArgumentException java.net.URISyntaxException: Relative path in absolute URI:

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, bigdata

My `hive-site.xml` configuration is

When I use hive:

`show databases;`

The exception that I'm getting is:

```
FAILED: IllegalArgumentException java.net.URISyntaxException: 
Relative path in absolute URI: file:./tmp/hive-root/root/74dc7e51-1d24-4397-9321-9b8c651ee212/hive_2016-12-04_22-55-36_784_2074916962149947374-1
```

Comment: <property>
    <name>hive.exec.scratchdir</name>
    <value>/tmp/hive-${user.name}</value>
    <description>HDFS root scratch dir for Hive jobs which gets created with write all (733) permission. For each connecting user, an HDFS scratch dir: ${hive.exec.scratchdir}/&lt;username&gt; is created, with ${hive.scratch.dir.permission}.</description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.exec.local.scratchdir</name>
    <value>tmp/hive-${user.name}/root</value>
    <description>Local scratch space for Hive jobs</description>
  </property>
  <property>

Comment: Please specify your question

Answer (score 3):

Change the hive-site.xml with below properties

```
<name>hive.exec.scratchdir</name>
<value>/tmp/hive</value>

 <name>hive.exec.local.scratchdir</name>
 <value>/tmp/hive</value>

<name>hive.downloaded.resources.dir</name>
<value>/tmp/hive/${hive.session.id}_resources</value>

<name>hive.scratch.dir.permission</name>
<value>733</value>
```